# Extending ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to extend an existing Concern in a different Rails project.
This module exists in a gem I'm requiring:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    #some stuff
  end

  def method_a
  end
end
```

And then in my project:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    #some other stuff
  end

  def method_b
  end
end
```

Result is, objects including Foo only have method_b, and only run #some other stuff on inclusion. Is there any way for all code under included to run, and all methods to be added?

EDIT: Both the gem and the project are mine, and I'm not dead set on using ActiveSupport::Concern if there's a more fitting solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't override or extend directly the concern. With a simple module it would be maybe useful, but concerns are set up to be explicitly extended:

```
module MyFoo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  extend Foo

  included do
    #some other stuff
  end

  def method_b
  end
end
```

Comment: This did not seem to work for me, but it did work if I change from `extend Foo` to `include Foo`